# I can't get an image on the left side of my Android XML Layout to appear properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml

Here is what is looks like and here is my XML code.

Can someone please post the fixed XML layout code for me and explain what I am doing wrong? I want the - symbol on the left to be all of the way left, just like the > symbol on the right side. The black text should be just to the right of the - symbol.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dip"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        android:divider="@null"       
         >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/infocells"
            android:divider="@null"  >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtKey"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtValue"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't have to do this with a TableLayout

Comment: OK can you show me how then instead of giving me a -1?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of `RelativeLayout` and using various property of it you can align your `TextView` and `ImageView` according to your other views.If u want to set a - to the left then make use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for you > to set it to the right of the layout

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageView` you can set your X position using [translationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atranslationX) like something below:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:translationX="-25"
   android:src="@drawable/minus" />
```

Just try it. This is a quick solution only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea on how you can do it. Give it a try.

```
<RelativeLayout>
           <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

           <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtKey"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDelete" />

           <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtValue"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtKey" />

           <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```